# Gradient a button using transparent in Android?

Tags: android, android-button

I'm trying to make a button's color to be a gradient from white to transperent to black. 
My problem is that the button is on top of an image which makes it impossible to use background.

I'm currently using the following code which doesn't build:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
    android:radius="14dp"
    />
<gradient
    android:angle="45"
    android:centerX="35%"
    android:centerColor="color/transparent"
    android:startColor="#E8E8E8"
    android:endColor="#171717"
    android:type="linear"
    />
<padding
    android:left="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp"
    />
<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#878787"
    />
```

**Error**

"error: 'color/transparent' is incompatible with attribute android:centerColor (attr) color.
Message{kind=ERROR, 
text=error: 'color/transparent' is incompatible with attribute android:centerColor (attr) color.
"

thanks for the helpers!

Comment: Try `@color/transparent` instead of just `color/transparent` (assuming you've got a color resource named "transparent" in your app). The `@` is very important here.

Comment: Hi @Ben P. I don't have a color transperent on my app. I actually wont the middle of it will be transperent so the background image will be seen.

Comment: Try `#00000000` (eight zeroes); that's the hex representation of a fully transparent black.

Comment: @Ben P Thank you! You are nothing but AMAZING! I Love This Site!!!! #StackOverflowCommunityIsTheBest!